# conversion in C using pointers

Tags: c

Ive got it to compile with warnings. It does the conversion correctly but the unit actually reads as "EoL"

I am getting a missing "(" syntax error . I have looked it over quite a bit and cant seem to find it.

Also I am getting an error for :
hello.c:22: warning: conflicting types for âconvert_weightâ

I am using int, char and pointers in the respective function so don't understand the conflict

any ideas ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>




int main() {

  char newline, another = 'y';
  int weight1, weight2;
  char units1[4], units2[4];
  while (another == 'y') {
    printf("Enter a weight and the units of the weight (lbs or kgs)\n");
    scanf("%d %s", &weight1, units1);
    convert_weight(weight1, units1,&weight2, units2);
    printf("%d %s = %d %s\nAnother (y or n)\n", weight1, units1, weight2, units2);
    scanf("%c%c", &newline, &another);
  }
  return 0;
}
void convert_weight(int weight1, char  units1, int* weight2 , char  units2)
{
  char lbs[4]= "lbs";
  char kgs[4]= "kgs";
  int diffkgs =  strcmp(units1,kgs);
  int difflbs =  strcmp(units1,lbs);

  if (diffkgs==0){

    &weight2 = weight1 * 2.2;
    units2 = "lbs";
  }
  else if (difflbs==0){
    &weight2 = weight1 * .4545;
    units2 = "kgs";
  }

}
```

Ive Made some changes and now im only getting this syntax error message:

hello.c:23: error: expected â;â, â,â or â)â before âunits1â

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>




int main() {

  char newline, another = 'y';
  int weight1, weight2;
  char units1[4], units2[4];
  while (another == 'y') {
    printf("Enter a weight and the units of the weight (lbs or kgs)\n");
    scanf("%d %s", &weight1, units1);
    convert_weight(weight1, units1,&weight2, units2);
    printf("%d %s = %d %s\nAnother (y or n)\n", weight1, units1, weight2, units2);
    scanf("%c%c", &newline, &another);
  }
  return 0;
}


void convert_weight(int weight1, char[] units1, int* weight2 , char[]  units2)
{
  char lbs[4]= "lbs";
  char kgs[4]= "kgs";
  int diffkgs =  strcmp(units1,kgs);
  int difflbs =  strcmp(units1,lbs);

  if (diffkgs==0){

    *weight2 = weight1 * 2.2;
    units2 = "lbs";
  }
  else if (difflbs==0){
    *weight2 = weight1 * .4545;
    units2 = "kgs";
  }
```

Comment: Your parameter `units2` is of type `char`, which holds a single character. At the end of the function you have `units2 = "kgs";`. This won't work. You will need to fix its type.

Comment: `&weight2 = weight1 * 2.2;` -- that certainly isn't what you intend. Lose the `&` and replace it with a `*` and it probably is.

Comment: `units2 = "lbs";` -> `strcpy(units2, "lbs");` and needs prototype before main `void convert_weight(int weight1, char  *units1, int* weight2 , char  *units2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following version works, tested using the C compiler of Visual C++ 2013.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void convert_weight(int weight1, char  *units1, int* weight2 , char  units2)
{
  char lbs[4]= "lbs";
  char kgs[4]= "kgs";
  int diffkgs =  strcmp(units1,"kgs");
  int difflbs =  strcmp(units1,"lbs");

  if (diffkgs==0){

    *weight2 = weight1 * 2.2;
     units2 = "lbs";
  }
  else if (difflbs==0){
    *weight2 = weight1 * .4545;
    units2 = "kgs";
  }

}

int main() {

  char newline, another = 'y';
  int weight1, weight2;
  char units1[4], units2[4];
  while (another == 'y') {
    printf("Enter a weight and the units of the weight (lbs or kgs)\n");
    scanf("%d %s", &weight1, units1);

    convert_weight(weight1, units1,&weight2, units2);
    printf("%d %s = %d %s\nAnother (y or n)\n", weight1, units1, weight2, units2);
    scanf("%c%c", &newline, &another);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

You are having too many issues,

1. Either write function definition just above the main or just add a function prototype above main
   like this,

   void convert_weight(int weight1, char  *units1, int* weight2 , char  units2);
2. **strcmp(units1,"kgs");** takes a **pointer to a char**, rather than a **char** and its second value is a string so must be enclosed in double quotes. The same is true for "lbs" line.
3. As hinted by comments and other answers you would want a ***weight2 = weight1 * .4545;** rather **than &*weight2 = weight1 * .4545;** The **&** operator returns the address of pointer variable itself but ***** could be used to store/access a value at address pointed by the pointer (weight2 here).

Answer (score 2):

You have defined `convert_weight()` like this:

```
void convert_weight(int weight1, char  units1, int* weight2 , char  units2)
```

but you call it like this:

```
convert_weight(weight1, units1,&weight2, units2);
```

passing strings, and not chars as defined.

Comment: Additionally, since that function is not declared before its first use, the compiler assumes it returns an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted does not exhibit a missing '(' error.  However it has a number of other errors.  You should post the build log verbatim rather than paraphrasing or describing the errors.  Your original code produces the following at http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php:

```
main.c:21:6: warning: conflicting types for ‘convert_weight’ [enabled by default]
 void convert_weight(int weight1, char  units1, int* weight2 , char  units2)
      ^
main.c:15:5: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘convert_weight’ was here
     convert_weight(weight1, units1,&weight2, units2);
     ^
main.c: In function ‘convert_weight’:
main.c:25:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
   int diffkgs =  strcmp(units1,kgs);
   ^
In file included from main.c:2:0:
/usr/include/string.h:143:12: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
 extern int strcmp (__const char *__s1, __const char *__s2)
            ^
main.c:26:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
   int difflbs =  strcmp(units1,lbs);
   ^
In file included from main.c:2:0:
/usr/include/string.h:143:12: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
 extern int strcmp (__const char *__s1, __const char *__s2)
            ^
main.c:30:14: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
     &weight2 = weight1 * 2.2;
              ^
main.c:31:12: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
     units2 = "lbs";
            ^
main.c:34:14: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
     &weight2 = weight1 * .4545;
              ^
main.c:35:12: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
     units2 = "kgs";
```

The following, changed where indicated by end-line comments works, though there is plenty of ill-advised coding - but that's a different question.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void convert_weight(int weight1, char* units1, int* weight2 , char* units2) ; // ADDED

int main() {

  char newline, another = 'y';
  int weight1, weight2;
  char units1[4], units2[4];
  while (another == 'y') {
    printf("Enter a weight and the units of the weight (lbs or kgs)\n");
    scanf("%d %s", &weight1, units1);
    convert_weight(weight1, units1,&weight2, units2);
    printf("%d %s = %d %s\nAnother (y or n)\n", weight1, units1, weight2, units2);
    scanf("%c%c", &newline, &another);
  }
  return 0;
}

void convert_weight(int weight1, char* units1, int* weight2 , char* units2) // CHANGED
{
  char lbs[4]= "lbs";
  char kgs[4]= "kgs";
  int diffkgs =  strcmp(units1,kgs);
  int difflbs =  strcmp(units1,lbs);

  if (diffkgs==0){

    *weight2 = weight1 * 2.2; // CHANGED
    strcpy( units2, "lbs" ) ; // CHANGED
  }
  else if (difflbs==0){
    *weight2 = weight1 * .4545; // CHANGED
    strcpy( units2, "lbs" ) ; // CHANGED
  }

}
```